# to split an array into subarray in python

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I am new to programming and python programming. 
I have a tab delimited txt file that I have imported using `numpy.getfromtxt` and it looks like

```
[['chr' 'start' 'end' 'name' 'score' 'strand']
['chr1' '822979' '822980' 'CLL6.08_1_snv' '88.2' '+']
..., 
['chrX' '153986959' '153986960' 'CLL6.08_2678_snv' '500' '+']]
```

I want to split this data in subarrays with different chromosomes like

```
Chr1, Chr2 ...
```

I was trying something like this but getting an syntax error. I am trying to do so as I want to extract each chromosome data when conditionally.

```
import numpy as np  
data=np.genfromtxt("CLL608.txt",delimiter ="\t",dtype=None,skip_header=0)
subarray=(['Chr1':data[data[:,0]=='chr1'], 'Chr2':data[data[:,0]=='chr2']])
```

I would really appreciate any suggestion in this regard.

Comment: You may want to have a look at `pandas` and use its data frame data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make association in a list [] you have to use a dictionary {}

```
>>> subarray=({'Chr1':'bla'=='blu'})
>>> print subarray
{'Chr1': False}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `dict`-ionary, which takes a string (or any hashable object) and returns an arbitrary value. Use that to map your 'chr' names to sub-arrays with just those records:

```
sublists = {}  # empty dict
for record in data:
    key = record[0] # 'chr1' or whatever
    if key in sublists:   # already seen it?
        sublists[key].append(record)
    else:
        sublists[key] = [record]  # start new sublist
```

You can speed this up by knowing that in Python, the whole "I wish my dictionary had a default value for new keys" problem comes up *a lot*, and there are some standard solutions:

```
sublists = {}
for record in data:
    key = record[0]
    sublists.get(key, list()).append(record)
```

The `list()` creates a new, empty, list. Either the empty list, or a previously existing list, has the `record` appended.

Finally, you can speed that up even more by recognizing that iterating across a list and doing exactly one thing to it is a good use of the `map` function. Although generally you use the *result* of whatever you're doing, with map.

```
sublists = {}
map(data, lambda r: sublists.get(r[0], list()).append(r))
```

Finally, if your data happens to be *sorted* on the key value, you might use the [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools.groupby#itertools.groupby) function, which will handle the grouping logic for you if the data is already sorted. I mention these last two (`map` and `groupby`) because I suspect your dataset may be large, and performance may be an issue.